# Why would RuntimeBinderException occur at runtime calling an overloaded function?

Tags: c#

I've finally produced a minimal example that reproduces this error:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
class Program
{
    public byte[] Foo(byte[] p) { return new byte[0]; }
    public byte[] Foo(Guid? p) { return new byte[0]; }
    static Guid? ToGuid(string s) { return s == null ? null : (Guid?)new Guid(s); }
    void Bar()
    {
        dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{}");
        var id = d?.id?.ToString();
        Foo(ToGuid(id));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Bar();
    }
}
```

Bizarrely it's crashing at runtime calling Foo when d.id is null (or not a string), saying it can't resolve which version of Foo to call (The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties).  Why on earth isn't this resolved at compile time though? The `dynamic` shouldn't make a difference that I can see, and in fact even more weirdly if I add an explicit cast "`(Guid?)`" before `ToGuid...` it works as expected, and likewise if I instead write it as:

```
Guid? id = ToGuid(d.id?.ToString());
Foo(id)
```

which actually makes more sense anyway. It also works fine if I change "var" to "string".

I noticed that the exception is initially thrown from "System.Linq.Expressions.dll" which is a bit odd. The full stack trace is basically:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'FooService.Foo(byte[])' and 'FooService.Foo(System.Guid?)'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , FooService , Object )

Exception source is "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly"

Comment: Aren't you getting compilation error `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.Guid'` at `Guid? ToGuid(string s) { return uuid == null ? null : new Guid(uuid) }`?

Comment: Fixed, sorry...

Comment: That's because your example doesn't use dynamic. It only happens if the parameter to ToGuid( ) ultimately comes from a dynamically typed variable.

Comment: But further that site seems to use a very old version of C#, it won't even let me write `d?.id.ToString()` (which seems to be the key part). I'm using 7.1

Comment: Can' reproduce. Your code passig in an `d` with `id` null or whatever will run perfeclty fine.

Comment: Still investigating a minimal example that definitely reproduces it, my first attempt I realised was giving a different error about not being "not contain a definition for id" when doing `d.id?.ToString()`

Comment: The error you are getting is because the call is being resolved at runtime. You must be misunderstanding somehting in your code, somewhere you have a `Foo(dynamic)` call that is ambiguous (argument `null` being a primary supect although it can be many other scenarios)

Comment: Make sure you don't have an implicitly typed variable anywhere a `dynamic` is involved: `string id = d.id?.ToString();` will make sure `id` is `string` or fail at runtime but `ar id = d.id?.ToString();` will chug on happily with `id` being `dynamic`.

Comment: There's no `var`.  But `d` is in fact a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken which seems to be what is allowing `d.id?.ToString()` to execute OK at runtime but fail later, though it's still not making much sense.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

Comment: Even with updated code, still no repro. Runs without exception. Don't just keep nibbling away trying to add code here. Take time to create a [mcve] so that *we can see what you're seeing*.

Comment: Trust me I'm trying. Turns there *was* a `var` - instead of `string id` the original code is `var id`, and in fact this is key to triggering the behaviour too, but I still can't get a minimal compilable example to reproduce it.  The disassembly around the function call is extremely odd too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we have the `var` variant I can reproduce the issue. And the issue is `null`s. You may think that the return type of `ToGuid` *must* be a `Guid?` because you're assuming knowledge that the compiler doesn't work with. So far as it's concerned, in `Bar` it's looking at an `id` with type `dynamic`<sup>1</sup>. This means that it's going to assume that *whatever* `ToGuid` returns it'll store in a `dynamic` temp variable.

In this case, it returns `null` and under the covers, `dynamic` is just `object`. At that point, we've lost any *compile time* type information about the return type from `ToGuid`. If it wasn't `null`, before it resolves `Foo` it would effectively call `GetType` on the instance. But that's not possible here. It has `null` and two equally good/bad candidates it could call with a `null` reference. It's as if you'd written `Foo(null);` (which generates the equivalent error at compile time).

Inserting an explicit cast - `Foo((Guid?)ToGuid(id));` gives the runtime sufficient information *at the callsite* to be able to unambiguously select the correct overload of `Foo` you wanted it to choose.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bear in mind that whatever the type of the `id` property on `d` is, it may have a `ToString` method that shadows the one from `object`. It cannot assume it returns a `string` so `id` is `dynamic` too.

Comment: But at compile time there's only one possible return type from ToGuid (regardless of the parameter type) - so I'm still confused as to why it doesn't resolve the ambiguity at compile time.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need the Newtonsoft type either, just ```void Bar()
  {
   dynamic id = null;
   Foo(ToGuid(id));
  }
``` is enough.

And yes I understand (now!) that `id` was of type dynamic.  But that doesn't properly explain why ToGuid(id) is also of type dynamic.

Comment: @DylanNicholson - because the whole point of `dynamic` is to defer these sorts of decisions until runtime. The only expressions that use `dynamic` variables and *don't* assume the type of *that* expression is also `dynamic` are explicit casts and constructor calls.

Comment: Well I've ticked your answer even if I'm not particularly satisfied it makes sense for the compiler to behave this way.

Comment: Also I've now realised in my current code it's unnecessarily calling ToGuid via run-time binding too.